# How to use which.min(i) in a loop to return the minimum value per set in each variable?

Tags: r

I´m kind new to R programming and I´m trying to get the minimum value by group in each variable. I have more than 300 variables and am trying to run which.min() inside a loop.
Here´s a dummy dataset:

```
df <- data.frame("Set" = c(rep("A",3),rep("B",3),rep("C",3)),
                 "Pair" = rep(c("a","b","c"),3),
                 "y" = c(4,5,6,4,5,8,9,8,7), 
                 "x" = c(11,13,10,15,14,16,12,18,17),
                 "z" = c(19,20,21,22,23,24,25,26,27))
```

data:

```
  Set Pair y  x  z
1   A    a 4 11 19
2   A    b 5 13 20
3   A    c 6 10 21
4   B    a 4 15 22
5   B    b 5 14 23
6   B    c 8 16 24
7   C    a 9 12 25
8   C    b 8 18 26
9   C    c 7 17 27
```

I´m trying:

```
library(data.table)
RES <- setDT(df[,c(1,2,3)])[ , .SD[which.min(y)], by = Set]
for (i in 2:3){
  df2 <- as.data.frame(df[,c(1,2,..i+2)])
  res2 <- setDT(df2)[ , .SD[which.min(i+2)], by = Set]
  RES <- cbind(RES,res2)
  rm(res2)
}
```

My desired output:

```
  Set Pair y Set.1 Pair.1  x Set.2 Pair.2  z
1   A    a 4     A      c 10     A      a 19
2   B    a 4     B      b 14     B      a 22
3   C    c 7     C      a 12     C      a 25
```

The problem is within which.min() that does not accept i+2 or nor even i.
How do I iterate through columns using which.min()? I tried other functions too, but the closest I got was with this one. I could do just `res2 <- setDT(df)[ , .SD[which.min(x)], by = Set]`, but I have many many columns to go through. If you have another solution, I would be very happy to learn. Thank you!

Comment: `mo9.1` is unknown. Please make sure it is reproducible.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an approach which uses `lapply` to loop through the columns of interest of `y:z` (e.g., x, y, and z). If we could simplify and only worry about the minimum, this is what it would look like:

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df)
dt[, lapply(.SD, min), by = Set, .SDcols = y:z]
```

However, you are interested in both the matching `Pair` with the minimum value of the columns. To do that, we use `lapply` to instead return the two values of interest. Then, to have the data combine correctly, we `do.call('c', ...)`

```
library(data.table)
dt = as.data.table(df)
dt[, do.call('c', 
             lapply(.SD,
                    function(x) {
                      wm = which.min(x)
                      list(pair = Pair[wm],val =  x[wm])
                      })),
   by = Set,
   .SDcols = y:z]

##    Set y.pair y.val x.pair x.val z.pair z.val
## 1:   A      a     4      c    10      a    19
## 2:   B      a     4      b    14      a    22
## 3:   C      c     7      a    12      a    25
```

Comment: Thank you for your reply. 'c' in do.call is for combine? I tried to run your second code with .SDcols = s1:s36. That´s the name of my variables. The numbers in the variables does not mean anything, it is just part of the name. So, my first 6 variables after "Set" and "Pair" are s1, s18, s4, s251, s3, s36.  It did returned the results correctly for the values, but the naming is all weird. I got s11, s12, s181, s182, s41, s42, s2511, s2512, s31, s32, s361, s362. It is putting the integer 1 at the end of each name repeating it and putting the integer 2.

Comment: Yes, `c` is for combine. You can also look at `?c` for the help file. Also, see edit - the `list(Pair[wm], x[wm])` line was changed and it seems to have better naming.